# Mac OSX - how do I do a search and replace across an entire directory for a particular text?

Tags: macos, unix, replace, terminal, find

I have the following folder structure -

```
Foo/
   y.c
   Bar/
      a.c
   Baz/
      b.c
   Pie/
      m.c
      Ham/
         x.c
```

All I need to simply do is replace every instance of `Alice()` in the Foo/ directory, which is my current directory and turn it into `Bob()`. I'm having the hardest time with this trivial issue.

I've tried variants of :

```
find ./ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i ’s/Alice\(\)/Bob\(\)/g’
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/Alice\(\)/Bob\(\)/g' '{}' \;
sed 's/Alice\(\)/Bob\(\)/g ' `grep -l -R 'Alice\(\)' .`
```

with `exec` instead of `xargs` and seem to be gettings errors like :

```
Can't do inplace edit: . is not a regular file.
sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence
```

and so on. Can someone please help me out here?

Comment: You shouldn't escape `(` and `)`. It has opposite meaning as you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mac built-in BSD `sed` is not the same as GNU `sed`.

### BSD sed

```
/usr/bin/sed -i '' 's/foo/bar/g' input.txt
```

***Note:** A zero-length `''` is needed to edit in-place.*

### GNU sed

```
/usr/local/bin/sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' input.txt
```